# How to get the draggable value multiple time

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am using jquery Draggable and Droppable option, it's working fine. But, I want to use the draggle option multiple time. Is ther any way to do that.

For Example : I want to drap "Hello you" two times and "Hello me" one time.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/rohit_0903/13ugjnce/

**My Code:**

*HTML*

```
<input>
<input>
<input>
<span>hello you</span>
    <br>
<span>hello me</span>
```

*SCRIPT*

```
$("input").droppable();

$("span").draggable();
```

Answer (score 0):

To stop dragging any element you got to destroy its drag event for the respective dragged control. Have a look in below code:

```
var you=0,me=0;
$("input").droppable();
$("span.you,span.me").draggable({
    stop: function() {        
    if($(this).hasClass('you'))
    {
        you++;
    }
    else if($(this).hasClass('me'))
    {
       me++;
    }
    dragDestroy($(this).attr('class'));
  }
});
function dragDestroy(clas)
{
 switch(clas)
 {
    case 'you ui-draggable ui-draggable-dragging':
            if(you==2)
            {
                $('span.you').draggable( 'destroy' );//destroying drag event
            }
            break;
    case 'me ui-draggable ui-draggable-dragging':
        if(me==1)
        {
            $('span.me').draggable( 'destroy' );//destroying drag event
        }
        break;
 }
}
```

[Working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L06zhnrs/)